# Nested for loop - range

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

beginner/noob here:
If anyone could help explain what is actually happening (behind the code) in simple terms, would be greatly appreciated
trying to experiment, why does the second script not output apple?

```
one = ["apple", "banana", "republic"]

for i in range(len(one)):
    for j in range(i + 1):
        print(one[i])
```

output

```
   apple
   banana
   banana
   republic
   republic
   republic
```

whereas

```
one = ["apple", "banana", "republic"]

for i in range(len(one)):
    for j in range(i):
        print(one[i])
```

output doesn't contain apple

```
   banana
   republic
   republic
```

Comment: Did you notice the pattern? Your first example prints 1 time, 2 times, 3 times.  Your second example prints 0 times, 1 time, 2 times.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a fundamental concept in most programming languages: Ranges and indices begin at 0, and exclude the "last" element.

So `range(len(one))` will include the numbers 0, 1, and 2.

So then in your second code example, in the first step of the outer loop `i` will be `0`. And then the inner loop would say "Okay, now loop over `j` starting from 0 and running until, but excluding, 0`. Which means, actually, don't run at all.

You can check this by typing `print(list(range(0))` and that should be an *empty* list.

That's why in your second example the apple doesn't get printed.

Answer (score 0):

The first run of your loop:

```
for i in range(len(one)):
    for j in range(i):
        print(one[i])
```

i = 0 => j = 0 to 0: it means that the "j"-cycle condition already done and next iteration of `i` should be used. And one[i=0] item will not be outputed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help, I understand the reason behind now. I appreciate your time for explaining it to me